# Why is sqlite db database locked when there's no other python process writing to it at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

In here [Python sqlite3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants), I see that the default timeout is 5 seconds.
I do connect without specifying the timeout. python 3.7.

I have 2 python processes that write to the same DB. This file.db is in WAL mode. I see the 2 files -shm and -wal there.

I get this exception `sqlite3.Error:  'database is locked'`

At the time of this exception, the other process had finished its transaction (got out of the `with` context manager) and had gone to sleep with `signal.pause`
The file is on a locally mounted regular hard drive.

How can i investigate what's happening besides doing:

1. I can check fuser -v on myfile.db

I do assume that any other writing process only locks the database while it is executing a transaction. Once it's finished, it releases the lock.

Besides, in WAL mode, are things supposed to work differently?

Comment: from the cli sqlite, i just tried to UPDATE a table, and I also the db is locked.
There are 2 python processes that have opened it in write mode (fuser shows F).

I understand python sqlite module surrounds all UPDATE statements with a transaction. So after the .execute() has returned, the transaction is finished, and so if the process is sleeping cause of signal.pause, it should has unlocked the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:
The sqlite3 module opens transactions implicitly before a Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e. INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE), and commits transactions implicitly before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than SELECT or the aforementioned).

In my case, I only had a `UPDATE`, which means a BEGIN was inserted by sqlite3 before that, followed but the `signal.pause()`, which means I hadn't encountered a non DML stmt, and the transaction was still active right before sleeping

The other process tried to run a `UPDATE` while the 1st was still asleep ( and the transact active).

I've added a  `conn.commit()` before `signal.pause()`